# Trying to create linear equation solver with steps in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to create a function to expand the brackets in a linear equation. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the function to function, and I have been getting errors. Below is the code I wrote:

```
List openBracket(List<String> equationComponents) {
    List eqtComponents = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < equationComponents.length; i++) {
      if (containsBracket(equationComponents.get(i))) {
        eqtComponents.addAll((equationComponents.get(i)));
      } else {
        eqtComponents.add(equationComponents.get(i));
      }
    }
    return eqtComponents;
  }
```

This is the error that I am facing:

"**The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'.**"

I can't seem to solve the problem.

I have searched on YouTube and Google but found no solutions to the problem. I Have been trying to find alternatives to the ".get" method but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `myList.elementAt(x)` or just `myList[x]` for list.

```dart
equationComponents.elementAt(x)
```

```dart
List openBracket(List<String> equationComponents) {
  List eqtComponents = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < equationComponents.length; i++) {
    if (containsBracket(equationComponents.elementAt(i))) {
      eqtComponents.addAll([equationComponents[i]]); // add all need list 
    } else {
      eqtComponents.add(equationComponents.elementAt(i));
    }
  }
  return eqtComponents;
}
```

More about [List](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html)